# apache error with one php file and not another yet identical

Tags: php, apache

I ran into some problems with a server 500 error on a particular file which worked fine locally until I uploaded it to host.

So dumbed the file down to as simple as a php gets. The code is:

```
 <?php
  echo "hello,hello";
 ?>
```

When it is called test4.php it gives the 500 error. Then when I rename it to test5.php it works, fails on test6.php

Dumps of two identical files - one works, one not:

```
 [~/www/]# hexdump test5.php
0000000 3f3c 6870 0a70 6365 6f68 2220 6568 6c6c
0000010 2c6f 6568 6c6c 226f 0a3b 3e3f 000a     
000001d
 [~/www/]# hexdump test4.php
0000000 3f3c 6870 0a70 6365 6f68 2220 6568 6c6c
0000010 2c6f 6568 6c6c 226f 0a3b 3e3f 000a     
000001d
```

test7.php works

test11.php fails

testtest.php fails

cp test5.php dent.php - works

cp dent.php zephod.php - works

cp dent.php test11.php - works - didn't before

cp test11.php testtest.php - works - didn't before

cp test7.php to vest7.php - works

```
enter code here
```

Any clues as to what could be going on here?
Some other details below.
Many thanks
Kevin

```
[~/www/]# httpd -version
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 61: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 62: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/usr/sbin/httpd: line 63: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Server version: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix)
Server built:   May 16 2014 07:50:36
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.24.18 rev9999 +cloudlinux



Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xxx:443
Request URL:https://www.server.net/dm/test4.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.server.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2124.3 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:657
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Tue, 19 Aug 2014 21:16:09 GMT
Server:Apache

    contents of .htaccess (http_s modified to h_t_t_p_s for posting purposes)


     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) h_t_t_p_s://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Say, those two ticks `\`` after `echo "hello,hello";` aren't part of your code, right?

Comment: `hexdump -C` is usually more readable (especially as you're using a single-byte charset). However, if the contents is the same... I would say the problem may be in the running binaries: does your webserver log _why_ it gives a 500? I assume you enabled both apaches & phps error reporting to the max?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: nope, not in the hexdump at least.

Comment: @Wrikken It's posted in the question's code. OP should remove them. Didn't get a response from the OP about my question to him. Edit: thanks.

Comment: Or we do it for him now, as it's clearly a lef-over of getting to grips with the markdown formatting ;)

Comment: ewe, sorry about the formatting... I had a few problems posting the message due to SO thinking some parts were code. As you spotted the ticks weren't in the php. Never saw them here til you spotted it.  Also wget behaves the same - though it says server error I wanted to rule client out. I will turn up the debug - tho' leasing a host and limited capability. doesn't behave like this on local apache with same files. Never saw this before. SoftException in Application.cpp:256:... public_html/dm/test4.php" is writeable by group is in log a lot..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should kick myself for this or, at best, fess up.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 theuser theuser   29 Aug 20 04:08 test22.php
-rw-r--r--  1 theuser theuser   29 Aug 17 07:59 test2.php
```

I must have had a perm 0664 and duplicated it.
I was transferring some files from another box to this one. When I checked perms and changed them from 664 to 644 the penny dropped.
Won't be making that mistake again.

Kevin

Comment: `cp -a` is nice one to rmemember :)